# Netbeans on OSX Yosemite: Starting Tomcat in debug mode is failing

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, netbeans, jdwp

I have installed Tomcat8 using homebrew on OSX 10.10.3.

Here is how I have configured ***tomcat-users.xml***:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd">

    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="admin"/>
    <user password="admin" roles="manager-script,admin" username="admin"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Tomcat8 starts from Netbeans and deploys my war correctly, except when in ***debug*** mode.

When I start in debug mode, I get the following error: `Starting of Tomcat Failed`
and the following output is generated in the Tomcat log:

> FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
>   ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
>   ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]

To me this is saying that the dubugging port is being locked by another process. Based on the **catalina.sh** file, the JPDA_ADDRESS="localhost:8000".

I'm new to Mac, so in this case, with Windows, I would just kill the java processes running in the Process Explorer.

I found some articles suggesting to execute `netstat` commands and others mentioning to use the `lsof` command to look for the PID to kill.

However neither commands rendered results for port 8000 so I logged out in an attempt to close whatever app is using the port.

After logging back in the problem remains. What gives? What secret mac trick am I not finding??

Comment: Have you tried the same in console?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No, I ended up re installing tomcat